# Adding two numbers using macros failed to execute

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

How to add 2 numbers using macros? I tried below but i am not able to execute.

```
Sub auto_open()
       n1 = InputBox("enter fiest number")
     n2 = InputBox("Enter 2nd number")
      Range("a1").Value = n1 + n2
End Sub
```

Comment: You could also convert them to numbers like `[A1] = CDbl(n1) + CDbl(n2)`. Cbld stands for ConvertToDouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting : I just checked it and it works :-)

Is there an actual error message or do you just not see any effect ?

Where have you placed the code exactly ?

You do not specify a worksheet before `Range("a1").Value` so that the result may be written where you don't expect it.

**EDIT**/PS : if you want to add them as numbers you might need to give `n1` and `n2` a numeric data type (even though VB lets you do almost anything unchecked), otherwise here they seem to be concatenated as strings.

Comment: Thanks for ur help.....yes i declared n1 and n2 as integers. so is it mandatory to declare the variables?

Comment: No it's not mandatory in VB (unless you use `option explicit`) but typing the variables may guard you from making mistakes and help you find errors.